# Java recursion sum of odd even

Tags: java, recursion

I have to write a java code (its not a homework )

We take a method int n and we return :

If (n positive and odd )--> 1+3+5+...+n

If (n positive and even) --> 2+4+6+..+n

If (n negative or zero) --> return 0

I know how to do these three separately,but together?

For example If (n positive and even) --> 2+4+6+..+n

```
public int addeven(int n)
 {
  if(n<0)
  {
    return 0;    
  }
  if(n%2 != 0 && n>0 )
  {
    return (n+addeven(n-1));
  }

}
```

Also what exactly does return (n+addeven(n-1)) mean here?

Comment: if it's not a homework, what kind of application needs this function? :-D

Comment: None.I am teaching myself Java and this is an example solved in the book but I am trying to do this on my own because I have always had issues with recursion.

Comment: This shouldn't compile. Methods with non-void return type must have a return statement on every possible execution path. Your method doesn't satisfy that condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both cases you need `n + (n-2) + (n-4) ...` so this should work:

```
public int addStrange(int n) {
    if (n <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return n + addStrange(n - 2);
}
```

Comment: What does addStrange(n-2) mean?

Comment: It means the value of `addStrange` with parameter `n-2`. This is what recursion means. Think of it like `f(x) = x + f(x-2)`.

Comment: I mean the parameter (n-2).Yes,I have learned about method calls.

Comment: @KamiH - `(n - 2)` takes the current value of `n`, subtracts `2` from it and passes that value as the parameter to the call.

Comment: And that code can be condensed to `return (n <= 0 ? 0 : n + addStrange(n - 2));`

Answer (score 0):

> Also what exactly does return (n+addeven(n-1)) mean here?

The outer parentheses are unnecessary so it's really

```
return n+addeven(n-1);
```

What that means is return to the caller the sum of n and the result of calling addeven with n - 1.  This call to addeven is the recursive part of the function.  You are calling the same method that you are currently in but with a different parameters.  Java (along with all non-archaic languages) will allow this. It keeps track of each unfinished call on the 'stack'.  It's important that your recursive function eventually returns without calling itself or you have *infinite recursion* and will get a *stack overflow*.

Answer (score -1):

Why use recursion at all? For example, if n is even, the answer is (n+2)*n/4

Comment: Because it's a self-assigned exercise in recursion (according to comment).

Comment: Ah - I had only seen his original post, which says nothing about trying out recursion.

Comment: Well, title kinda does. ;-)